# Limit sed to certain character range in a line

Tags: sed

I have a large one line file containing hex codes and I'd like to use sed to find patterns within certain character range of that line.

So far i've tryed this witout succes something like

```
echo abc123abc123abc123 | sed 's/^\(123\{8,14\}\)/\456/g'
```

I'd like it to output

```
abc123abc456abc123
```

(replace the pattern 123 only if found between the characters position 8 to 14)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you have "a large one line file", are you only interested in processing positions 8-14, or is your example a place holder for a larger problem? Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This replaces the first occurrence of `123` within the character positions 8 to 14 with `456`:

```
$ echo abc123abc123abc123 | sed -r 's/^(.{7,11})123/\1456/'
abc123abc456abc123
```

With Mac OSX (BSD), try:

```
sed -E -e 's/^(.{7,11})123/\1456/'
```

This works by looking for the pattern `^(.{7,11})123` and replacing it with the match in parens, `\1` and `456`.  If `123` starts in the 8th position, that means that it has seven characters that precede it.  If it finishes in the 14th position, that means that it has 11 characters which precede it.  That is why we match `^(.{7,11})`.

#### Global Replace

If you want to replace all occurrences of 123 with 456 provided that the 123 occurs within positions 8 and 14, then use:

```
sed -r ':again; s/^(.{7,11})123/\1456/; t again;'
```

This keeps repeating the substitution until there are no more strings `123` within the character range.

On OSX/BSD, try:

```
sed -E -e ':again' -e 's/^(.{7,11})123/\1456/' -e 't again'
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to change is the matching pattern:

```
^.{8}[^0-9]{0,6}([0-9]{3}).*$
```

Here, I presumed that you want to replace only digits `0-9`.
If that's not what you wanted you must provide more information, source data example and specify *formally* how to match the sequence to substitute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
echo abc123abc123abc123 | awk '{a=substr($0,1,6);b=substr($0,7,6);c=substr($0,13);sub(/123/,"456",b);print a b c}' file
abc123abc456abc123
```